# Python CSV writing not in order with subfunctions

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a application for a research purpose and I need obviously to save everything the user does in a tracking data file.

I currently struggle with writing the data in the right order into a csv file through different classes. the code with the problem looks like this:

main.py:

```
import csv
import classA

dataFile = open('data.csv', mode='w')
dataWriter = csv.writer(dataFile, delimiter=';')

dataWriter.writerow(['a'])
classA.functionA()
dataWriter.writerow(['c'])
```

classA.py:

```
import csv

dataFile = open('data.csv', mode='a')
dataWriter = csv.writer(dataFile, delimiter=';')

def functionA():
    dataWriter.writerow(['b'])
```

the generated CSV-File looks like this:

```
a
c
b
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the generated output? Are you saying you *don't* get that output? And why not pass in the `dataWriter` object from `main` to `functionA()` instead of opening the file there too?

Comment: Everything is as it should be. What is the problem?

Comment: Also be careful with your naming scheme, since `classA.py` is not actually a `class` but a module.

Comment: this was a major mistake of mine. now the generated csv file above shows the real output so you can see the problem. thanks for the other suggestions.

Comment: My best guess, is that the output is buffered, as the file is open by something else (your main module) - the submodule does not block, as writerow seems to be non-blocking, so.. the output is appended to the file, after the file is closed by the main process..  try providing datawriter to moduleA either by a global variable, a parameter to the function, or via a class with an initialiser